# Looking for open imbalanced datasets

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for imbalanced classification datasets to experiment with using synthetic data, ideally with a minor class of less than 10%. Does anyone know specific ones? Should be open to the public with no limitation of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most multi-class datasets can be turned into skewed binary classification datasets.
For example, the default scikit-learn [digits dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_digits.html) contains ~10% `1` and ~90% `not-1` images.

That being said, the [UCI Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html) hosts many datasets that are skewed, one that's quite skewed is this SMS spam dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/SMS+Spam+Collection

Another organisation that hosts *free but not open* datasets is [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/), one of their datasets that's very skewed is the following:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge

Comment: its not open data if you have to register, agree to terms, and give your phone number for verification.

Comment: This specific dataset should be open as it consists of Wikipedia comments, however, I'll verify and possibly correct when I get home.

Comment: that process i described is this specific dataset on kaggle

Comment: @albert you're right, I've added a similar open dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Also found this one: https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud - also taken from Kaggle.